# Trying to get webGL (2d) drawing to work. Can't see my triangles

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I'm trying to draw a simple quad via webgl. Here is some data:

vertex data: (2 floats per vertex)
0: 0
1: 0
2: 1
3: 0
4: 1
5: 1
6: 0
7: 1

tex coords: (doesnt really matter)
0: -1
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: -1
6: -1
7: -1

Indices:
0: 3
1: 0
2: 1
3: 3
4: 1
5: 2

Shaders:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
    uniform highp vec3 uColor;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    uniform int uSamplerCount;

    void main(void) {
    highp vec4 texColor =vec4(uColor, 1.0);
    if(uSamplerCount > 0)
        texColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //just white for now
    }
</script>

<!-- Vertex shader program -->
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute highp vec2 aVertexPosition;
    attribute highp vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform highp vec2 uPosition;
    uniform highp float uZLayer;

    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(uPosition + aVertexPosition, uZLayer, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    }
</script>
```

To me this seems all right. Now here I'm binding the buffers:

```
$p.UpdateBuffers = function ConvexSprite_UpdateBuffers() {
    this.gl.bindBuffer(34962 /* WebGLRenderingContext.ARRAY_BUFFER */, this.bVertexPositions);
    this.gl.bufferData(34962 /* WebGLRenderingContext.ARRAY_BUFFER */, this.rotatedPoints, 35044 /* WebGLRenderingContext.STATIC_DRAW */);

    // string s = rotatedPoints.join(",");
    // System.Console.WriteLine("Vertices: " + s);
    this.gl.bindBuffer(34962 /* WebGLRenderingContext.ARRAY_BUFFER */, this.bTextureCoords);
    this.gl.bufferData(34962 /* WebGLRenderingContext.ARRAY_BUFFER */, this.texCoords, 35044 /* WebGLRenderingContext.STATIC_DRAW */);
    //System.Console.WriteLine("Texcoords: " + texCoords.join(","));
    this.gl.bindBuffer(34963 /* WebGLRenderingContext.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER */, this.bIndices);
    this.gl.bufferData(34963 /* WebGLRenderingContext.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER */, this.triangles, 35044 /* WebGLRenderingContext.STATIC_DRAW */);
};
```

And this is how I'm drawing:

```
private void DrawScene()
    {
        gl.viewport(0, 0, (int)canvas.width, (int)canvas.height);
        gl.clear(GL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        testSprite.Draw(aVertexPosition, aTextureCoord, uColor, uPosition, uZLayer, uSampler, uSamplerCount);
    }
```

draw function:

```
public void Draw(uint aVertexPosition, uint aTextureCoord,
        WebGLUniformLocation uColor, WebGLUniformLocation uPosition, WebGLUniformLocation uZLayer, WebGLUniformLocation uSampler, WebGLUniformLocation uSamplerCount)
    {

        //position
        gl.uniform2f(uPosition, this.position.x, this.position.y);
        gl.uniform1f(uZLayer, this.position.z);
        gl.uniform3f(uColor, 1f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.uniform1i(uSamplerCount, 0);

        //vertex data
        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, bVertexPositions);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, bTextureCoords);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoord, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bIndices);

        //texture
       // gl.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
       // gl.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
       // gl.uniform1i(uSampler, 0);

        //draw
        gl.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, triangles.length, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
```

Unfortunately all I'm getting is a black screen. The triangles are ccw, and in the 0-1 position range. Shouldn't this draw something to the screen ? What am I forgetting here ?

Comment: Any console error? Try rendering just red pixels for start, and if you have issues, then you know it's in the shader part.

Answer (score 1):

What values are `this.position.x` and `this.position.y`? Given you have a 0,1 quad the best you're going to be able to do with this shader and those vertex coordinates is draw a quad on 1/4th of the canvas. The values you need to output have to be in clipspace (-1 <-> +1).

To convert from pixels to clipspace

```
clipX = pixelX / gl.canvas.width  * 2 - 1
clipY = pixelY / gl.canvas.height * 2 - 1
```

for width and height in clipspace from pixels

```
clipWidth  = pixelWidth  / gl.canvas.width  * 2
clipHeight = pixelHeight / gl.canvas.height * 2
```

The first thing I do when debugging a WebGL program that is not drawing is change the fragment shader to the simplest thing possible

```
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1); return;
```

If I see red where I expect it I know the issue is in the fragcoord. If I don't I know the issue is somewhere else.

Next I might use the [WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/) to see what values I'm passing in the uniforms. For example if `this.position.x` or `this.position.y` is greater than 1 or less than -2 then nothing is going to appear because your quad is 0 to 1 so `0 + 1` = 1 which means your quad will be off the right side or top side of the canvas. `1 + -2 = -1` in which case the quad will be off the left or bottom side of the canvas.

Some other things. You set it draw in white `gl_FragColor = vec4(1,1,1,1);` but the default webpage color is white and the default clear color is `0,0,0,0` (transparent black) which means unless you either (a) made a canvas with no alpha (b) set the clear color somewhere not show or (c) set the CSS for the page or the canvas to a different color you're not going to see anything.

Here's some code that draws quads at pixel locations

```js
"use strict";

window.onload = function() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position"); 
  
  // look up uniform locations
  var u_matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");
  var u_colorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  function rand(min, max) {
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min) | 0;
  }

  for (var ii = 0; ii < 300; ++ii) {
    var dstX = rand(0, gl.canvas.width - 20);
    var dstY = rand(0, gl.canvas.height - 20);
    var dstWidth = rand(10, 30);
    var dstHeight = rand(10, 30);

    // convert dst pixel coords to clipspace coords      
    var clipX = dstX / gl.canvas.width  *  2 - 1;
    var clipY = dstY / gl.canvas.height * -2 + 1;
    var clipWidth = dstWidth  / gl.canvas.width  *  2;
    var clipHeight = dstHeight / gl.canvas.height * -2;

    // build a matrix that will stretch our
    // unit quad to our desired size and location
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(u_matrixLoc, false, [
        clipWidth, 0, 0,
        0, clipHeight, 0,
        clipX, clipY, 1,
      ]);
      
    gl.uniform4f(u_colorLoc, Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);

    // Draw the rectangle.
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas { 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>  
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform mat3 u_matrix;

void main() {

   gl_Position = vec4(u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1), 1);
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>
```

If you don't get the matrix math [here's an article that explains it](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html).

One other suggestion, instead of a conditional on `uSamplerCount` you might consider just

```
gl_FragColor = uColor * texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
```

Then make a 1 pixel white texture

```
whiteTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, whiteTex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Float32Array([255,255,255,255]));
```

Now whenever you want to draw with a solid color then

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, whiteTex);
gl.uniform4f(uColorLocation, r, g, b, a);
```

Whenever you want to draw with a texture

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, someTexture);
gl.uniform4f(uColorLocation, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```